# How to display large numbers in y-axis using dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm passing a data to dygraph with a million value on y-axis but it is displayed with "e+" suffix. Is there a way to format y-axis display to "3000000" or "3M" instead?

[image]

Same with the value displayed in points

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding `labelsKMB: true` on options